# proxy not working for create-react-app in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy

I am working with reactjs(*create-react-app*) to create a dashboard application, In my application i am calling multiple host (*for that I have configured multiple proxies in package.json to avoid CORS*).
ex- *www.app.demo1.com, www.app.demo2.com, www.app.demo3.com...*

```
"proxy": {
    "/demo1/api/":{
  "target":"www.app.demo1.com"
},
"/demo2/api/":{
  "target":"www.app.demo2.com"
},
"/demo3/api/":{
  "target":"www.app.demo3.com"
}
}
```

in application i am calling like-

```
try{
   const host1 = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'? 
   'www.app.demo1.com/demo1/api': '/demo1/api/';
   const host2 = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'? 
   'www.app.demo2.com/demo2/api': '/demo2/api/';
   const host3 = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'? 
  'www.app.demo3.com/demo3/api': '/demo3/api/';
   const resp1 = axios.get(host1)
   const resp2 = axios.get(host2)
   const resp3 = axios.get(host3)
}catch(){}
```

in development: when making request to */demo1/api/* it is being proxied to
*www.app.demo1.com/demo1/api* and i am getting the response. but

in production: I have deployed the application on github pages, although I am getting the below error,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWLDC.jpg)

Can anybody help..

Comment: You need to add more details, what kind of error do you get in production?

Comment: `webpack-dev-server` proxies do not work in production. Check full answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Proxies are for development purposes only, and they are handled by `webpack-dev-server`. On production you need to make the calls to the actual host.

This is created because usually, on development, react is served by a standalone server meant just for that (hence, `webpack-dev-server`). On production, usually there is a backend (node? ruby? php?) that serves the pages and every call made is going to be to some endpoint with the same hostname.

Example:

In your development environment you have a node server running on port 3001 and your react code running on port 3000. When react fetches `/api/user`, you actually want `http://localhost:3001/api/user`, which points to your node server.

In your production environment, you have a server (nginx, maybe?) that forwards all `/api` calls to your node process, and for everything else it serves your react main `index.html` file (so you can use `react-router`, for example). In this case, whenever you request `/api/user`, this is going to be handled by your web server and routed properly.

Comment: If all the apis are hosted on a different domain and the react-app resides in a different domain, how can we configure nginx to handle this? @sergio-moura

Comment: Our client wants node to handle api requests and redirect it to appropriate api end point residing it on another domain. How do I deploy it?