# How to run a production build of create-react-app locally? Cors/proxy issues

Tags: create-react-app

The proxy URL in my package.json works great. The issue is my production build has differences (due to the build I suppose). I'd like to debug a production build locally. However my API calls all fail because the production build isn't using/aware of the package.json setting.

Should I be looking at creating a proxy server or something? Nginx?

related:

- [Create-React-App Proxy in Production Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911067/create-react-app-proxy-in-production-build)
- [proxy not working for create-react-app in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52877492/proxy-not-working-for-create-react-app-in-production)